# Excel: why do "remove duplicates" and "conditionally highlight duplicates" give different results?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting, duplicate

Obviously these tasks do different things! But I am using them to find out if I have duplicates :)

In excel I have a column which is a concatenation of all of the other columns.
(The formula is copied down across the entire dataset)

If I select this column and get it to 'conditionally highlight duplicates' hardly anything is highlighted i.e. it cannot identify them as duplicates.

but if I use the 'remove duplicates' option, it finds all of them without problem

What is causing this behaviour and how can I prevent it?

There are about 40,000 rows and 51 columns that include strings, dates, etc

**EDIT**:

concat string length is about 1000 characters,
example snippets from concat string= 01102991666920130No0EUR0DEFAULTDEFAULT11
another example= 107219No818.517149URA2001686920140Yes0GBP

Comment: How do you create the CF rule? Could you provide a sample about CF cannot find the duplicate but Remove Duplicate option can? What's the file format?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the data, some examples of duplicates that are found by one but not the other, etc.?  There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: it's just using the built in 'conditional formatting' "highlight cells" "duplicate values"

Comment: updated question with more info

Comment: Still not much for us to go on. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then come back and edit your question.